Using Go language in map how to check if the file name exist or not
I am new to Go language,
I have list of file names in the folder , now how do I check if the file name is same as what I am expected. Please suggest me how do I achieve this.  I know how to read the files from the folder
Givenvalue := orange.txt

    myDict := make(map[string]){
   “apple.txt”
    "banana.txt"
    "orange.txt" }

Response :=  myDict.contains (givenvalue)

If Response{
Return true
}

This is what I have tried :
// Read the directory entries
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(directory)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Process each file
    for _, file := range files {
                          Response :=  myDict.contains (file)
                                   If Response{
Return true
}
               }


Sure, thank you
